# if [ $(getprop | grep '[net.tcp.buffersize.default]: [4096,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208]') ]

Tags: android, bash, grep

What is wrong with this line?

```
if [ $(getprop | grep '[net.tcp.buffersize.default]:[4096,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208]') ]
```

it should return a true value if grep finds 'net.tcp.buffersize...' in the getprop output.

Answer (score 5):

The argument of `grep` is a [regular expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions). The characters `[`, `]` and `.` have a special meaning, so the argument isn't interpreted literally. To look for a literal string, pass the `-F` option to `grep`. To look for a line that is exactly that string and no more, pass `-F -x`.

The way you test the outcome of `grep` doesn't make any sense. `$(…)` takes the output (i.e. the matching lines) and splits them into words (since there are no double quotes around `$(…)`). Then these words (which would be pieces of the `getprop` output) are parsed as conditionals for the `[` builtin. To test whether some input contains a match with `grep`, test the return status of the `grep` command, and pass the `-q` option to suppress output.

```
if getprop | grep -q -F -x '[net.tcp.buffersize.default]:[4096,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208]'; then …
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems I can see:

1. In the `grep` command, you need to escape the left square bracket
2. The if statement does not need square bracket in this case

So, your statement should reads:

```
if getprop | grep '\[net.tcp.buffersize.default]:\[4096,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208]'
```

#### UPDATE

You also need to escape the dot:

```
if getprop | grep '\[net\.tcp\.buffersize\.default]:\[4096,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208]'
```

Or, as Gilles pointed out, you should use the -F to search for literal string instead of using regular expression.